# android studio calling button

Tags: java, android, button, call

I am trying to make an on click button which makes phone calls when pressed.
Here is my code for java:

```
public void CampusSafClick(View view){
    Intent callIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:6038994210"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

I understand how to make onclick buttons, so that is not the issue.

I have this code in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permision.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

I keep getting the error Unfortunately your app has stop working.

Comment: The app keeps crashing.

Comment: could you please share your xml and complete activity

Comment: Do you have a log or error message? That would help narrow it down.

Comment: I keep getting the error message: Unfortunately your app has stop working.

Comment: What type of error it is Like Permission error or else post the full error message

Comment: I think I found the answer. I need to go to the android permisions area or enter code: <uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.PHONE_CALL"
     android:maxSdkVersion="18" /> Where do I go to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ivCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (serviceListDates.get(position).getUser_mobile().length() != 0) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            alertDialog.setTitle("NKA SERVICE");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to Call ?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.call_icon);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ((DeliveredServiceOilActivity) mContext).callPhoneNumber
                            (serviceListDates.get(position).getUser_mobile());
                }
            });`enter code here
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        } else
            AlertUtils.SHOW_TOAST(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.please_add_number));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is the working code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialContactPhone("123123123");
        }
    });
}

private void dialContactPhone(final String phoneNumber) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nikola for the code. I just needed to put the uses permission above the application list instead of inside of it.

Answer (score 4):

You need `Action_Dial`,

use below code it will open Dealer with number specified.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

The `tel:` prefix is required, otherwhise the following exception will be thrown: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity.`

`Action_Dial` doesn't require any permission.

If you want to initiate the call directly without user's interaction, you can use action `Intent.ACTION_CALL`. In this case, you must add the following permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I need to enter code above the application list on the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code

```
intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+251999999999"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

and include in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For make a call using android, It can be implement using Intents.

```
public void MakePhoneCall(View view){
    Intent callIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9961907453"));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
           Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              return;
           }
           startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

I have this code in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permision.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

If you are using SDK version greater than Lolipop then you should include request permission.